# How much Old Monk is famous in other countries?

Tags: spirits

I believe that [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Monk) Rum from India is not limited to India but also having fans from around the world. Is this available in other countries? If it is, what is usage rate?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no such Rum for sale in all Latin America, in common liquor stores, malls or grocery stores. Maybe you can find one in a specialized place, or importing it via internet.

Answer (score 2):

Old Monk Run is sold in **Canada**, where I presently reside, but it is not all that popular here.

> Old Monk is sold by some retailers in Russia, USA, UK, Japan, UAE, Estonia, Finland, New Zealand, and Canada. It has also been ranked 5th among Indian spirits brands at the Impact International's 2008 list of "Top 100 Brands At Retail Value" with a retail value of US$240 million.
>
> There was a time when Old Monk dominated the rum market. There were other brands also but none came close in quality or popularity. About eight million bottles were sold annually. Today the sales are a quarter of that and they continue to decline. There were recent rumours about Old Monk closing down but it's makers Mohan Meakin Ltd, assured that Old Monk is not going to be taken off market. - [How popular is Old Monk rum outside India?](https://www.quora.com/How-popular-is-Old-Monk-rum-outside-India)

Comment: I've independently verified that it's sold in the USA as well, but I've never heard of it.  Seems to be a low to mid-priced offering, and not that popular here either.

Comment: In India, It is most famous dark rum and was launched in 1954, since then the company is running without any kind of promotional activity and there is no change in packaging also. Old Monk had been awarded gold medals at Monde World Selections since 1982. Also it is most used brand by Indian Army.